# What's the content of the conversation?

Tags: idioms, listening, test

I practiced a TOEFL(simulation) test yesterday, and I came across this question (which is in the listening section) that says :

https://www.mediafire.com/file/t9f0ev397vztmez/300.mp3
That's the link to the audio file I downloaded from the TOEFL(simulation) test.

The question goes like this:

W : I can't keep up with this car anymore.
M : I know exactly what you mean, I should (don't miss mine..?) <-- this is the part that I can't understand
Narrator : what does the man imply?

And the answer was "The man got rid of his car"
No matter how many times I listen to the audio, I still can't get it. Is that some kind of idiom or it's just me not listening carefully?

I'm looking forward to your answer.

Comment: Which simulator did you used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"I sure don't miss mine." Not should.

Answer (score 0):

This is a tricky one! The speaker says "I sure don't miss mine!" which is a casual and informal usage and way of emphasizing your point in a conversation. So he's strongly saying that since he got rid of his car, he has never missed it, meaning that he is implying he no longer has a car. So this is more of a case of maybe not recognizing an informal phrase than of you not understanding, since you seemed to grasp everything else perfectly!

If you're having trouble with some of the tricky wordings found in TOEFL, one website that I like to recommend is www.bestmytest.com because they have really in-depth, high quality lessons available that address just this sort of issue.

I hope this helped! Best of luck!